# How to save the p5.js canvas png file locally?

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

How can I access the png file created in p5.js canvas?
I have tried the p5 saveCanvas function which directly downloads the design in the browser.
I dont want it to download directly, I want to save it locally in order to access it later? (save it in a variable for further processing basically)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to store you can try `storeItem(key, value)` and then `getItem(key)`.

Another way to do this could be [saveFrames()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/saveFrames), as it has a call back function.

```
let img;
function draw() {
 background(mouseX);
 if (img) {
     image(img,50,50);
 }
}
 function mousePressed() {
 saveFrames('out', 'png', 1, 2, data => {
   let a = str(data[0].imageData);
     img = loadImage(a);
    });
 }
```

Yet I think Hasan's approach would work just fine.